# Prove or the disprove the existence of a limit of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the annulus defined, in polar coordinates, as

$$ A = \{ (r, \theta) \in [0, \infty) \times [0, 2\pi) : 2 \leq r \leq 3 \} \, .$$
Let $F: A \to A$, $F:(r, \theta) \mapsto (r, r \theta \text{ (mod } 2\pi))$.
Let $g : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Discuss the existence of the limit
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A g \circ F^{(n)}(x) \, \text{d}x \, ,$$
where $F^{(n)} = F \circ F \circ \dots \circ F$ denotes the composition of $F$ with itself $n$ times.

I cannot find a way to attack this problem. Here's what I tried: if $g \circ F^{(n)}$ converged, I think we could take the limit under the integral sign. So I tried to show the convergence of $F^{(n)}$. If it converged, then the limit function must send every point to a fixed point of $F$. So I determined the fixed points of $F$. But I don't think $F^{(n)}$ converges.

Comment: Is it possible you mean $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ because it would make your annular domain compact, which may be relevant here (i.e without compactness we can't be sure that g is bounded)

Comment: That is indeed the case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Now that you know its compact, you know $\int_A g dx$ certainly exists and is finite, you are correct that $F^{n}(x)$ will (almost surely, at least at irrational radii) not converge, but try proving that $\int_A g \circ F = \int_A g$, what you're investigating here is translation invariance of lebesgue measure, maybe try in one dimension first?

Comment: As a toy example, let $f: [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and $t_c: [0,1) \to [0,1)$ be a translation, i.e $t_c(x)=x+c \mod 1$, now can you show that $\int_0^1 f=\int_0^1 f \circ t_c$?

Comment: @mb- How is this translation invariance? Note that $F$ wraps around the concentric circles within the annulus multiple times, it doesn't translate them. Otherwise it would be $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r, r+\theta \pmod {2\pi})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on the unit circle, then

$$\tag 1 \lim_{a\to \infty}\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{iat})\,dt = \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\,dt.$$

As @Shalop said in the comments, that follows from periodicity. Now $F_n(re^{it}) = re^{ir^nt},$ so

$$\int_A g(F_n(x))\, dx = \int_2^3 \int_0^{2\pi}g(F_n(re^{it}))\,dt \,r\, dr=\int_2^3 \int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{ir^nt})\,dt \,r\, dr.$$

Call the inner integral $I_n(r).$ Because $r^n \to \infty$ for any $r\in [2,3],$ $(1)$ shows

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n(r) = \int_0^{2\pi} g(re^{it})\,dt.$$

We have the easy estimate $|I_n(r)| \le 2\pi\sup_A|g|.$ Thus the domimated convergence theorem shows

$$\int_2^3I_n(r)\,r\, dr \to \int_2^3\int_0^{2\pi} g(re^{it})\,dt\,r\, dr = \int_A g(x)\, dx .$$

So $\int_A g(x)\, dx$ is the desired limit.

Comment: Is the "follows from periodicity" part obvious? Because I can't see it intuitively. Also I think $F_n(re^{it}) \ne re^{ir^nt}$ in general: $F_2(\frac52, \frac56 \pi) = F(\frac52, \frac{\pi}{12}) = (\frac52, \frac{5}{24}\pi)$, while $\frac56 \pi (\frac52)^2 = \frac{125}{24}\pi = \frac{29}{24}\pi$ (mod $2 \pi$). Is that correct? I don't know if this makes a difference in your argument.

Comment: Take $r=n,$ an integer, and change variables for your first question. I believe $F(re^{it}) = re^{rit}$ is exactly what was intended.

Comment: Maybe the intended interpretation of the problem was that $F^{(n)}(re^{it})$ denotes $re^{ir^nt}$, but that's definitely not what the problem says literally.

Comment: @EricWofsey I can't make sense of what it says literally.

Comment: Literally, $F$ is the map defined by $F(re^{it})=re^{irt}$ _if_ $t\in[0,2\pi)$.  The restriction that $t\in[0,2\pi)$ makes this well-defined (and also discontinuous).

Comment: OK, that's not quite "literally" what it says.  But that seems to be the only reasonable interpretation under which $F$ would actually be a map $A\to A$.

Comment: It's possible my interpretation is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably overkill, as you are not asked to give the value of the limit.
But let $f_r(\theta)=r\theta \ (\mbox{mod } 2\pi )$ for $2\leq r \leq 3$. This is known in ergodic theory as the beta-transformation of the interval (here beta is $r$). It is known to be ergodic w.r.t. Lebesgue (for all $r>1$ in fact). Lebesgue is however not the invariant density. There is an $L^1$ function $h_r(\theta)$ so that for continuous $g$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$
$$  \int_0^{2\pi} g(r,f_r^{(n)}(\theta)) d\theta \rightarrow \int_0^{2\pi} g(r,\theta) h_r(\theta) d\theta $$ for every $r$ (not just a.e.). The function $h_r(\theta)$ should be is measurable w.r.t. $(r,\theta)$ (but I have no reference for this). Modulo this, using Fubini and dominated convergence:
$$  \int_2^3\int_0^{2\pi} g(r,f_r^{(n)}(\theta)) r \;d\theta \;dr \rightarrow \int_2^3\int_0^{2\pi} g(r,\theta) h_r(\theta) r \; d\theta \; dr $$
But this is probably not the expected answer.

Note, however, that in general the limit is not $\int_A g \; dx$ which is not the correct answer.

Comment: I think you mean to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{2\pi} g(r \cos(r^n \theta),r \sin(r^n \theta)) d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} g(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)d\theta$. Which is basically a consequence of periodicity.

Comment: I think it is easier to think of it in polar coordinates. When $r$ is not an integer it is correct but needs a proof. Note that the map $F$ is not continuous.

Comment: Sure, but your answer is written as though $g$ is defined on $[2,3] \times [0,2\pi]$, when it is in fact defined on the image of that set under a polar coordinate transformation. In other words an abuse of notation. I didn't mention $F$ being continuous - that's not needed.

Comment: I don't really follow. You're saying that, if $A_r$ is the circle of radius $r$, then $F^{(n)}(A_r)=A_r$ for every $n$? I agree, but how does this help?

And is $F^{(n)}(r, \theta)$ really equal to $(r, r^n \theta(\text{mod} 2\pi))$? I mean, surely $r(r \theta (\text{mod} 2 \pi)) (\text{mod} 2\pi) \ne r^2 \theta(\text{mod} 2\pi))$?

Comment: OK, I see. Then it is a different problem (I thought of simply periodically continuing). I'll look into this...

Comment: @unumileappassionato May I ask in what context you came across this problem?

Comment: Surely in this instance $h_r(\theta) = 1$ gives the correct answer? The $F^{(n)}$ term in the integral has the effect (in the limit) of "averaging" $g$ over the angle?

Comment: No, there is averaging, but not uniformly. Except when $r=2$ or $r=3$, Lebesgue measure (in the angles) is not invariant under $f_r$. This makes the problem non-trivial.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Wouldn't the values of $F^{(n)}(r,\theta)$ become "uncorrelated" for nearby values of $r$, so that (except for rational $r$, a set of measure zero) the integral would be like choosing a uniformly-random value of $\theta$ for each $r$ value in the integral?

Comment: No in general smaller values of $\theta$ are 'favored' by iteration. Think of r=2.5 for which $f_r([0,2\pi])$ covers $[0,\pi]$ three times, but $[\pi,2\pi]$ only twice. This phenomena will be accentuated when iterating $f_r$.

Comment: Are there irrational values of $r$ for which the invariant distribution of the map is non-uniform?

Comment: I don't think irrationality comes into play. For all $2<r<3$ the image will cover the end part less. It follows that Lebesgue is not invariant (so no uniformity). To see what you actually get is less obvious.

Comment: @H. H. Rugh It was an entrance examination problem for an Italian school (SNS)

Comment: Ok, SNS has a very good level. What year of entrance? But anyway, probably one is supposed to argue for convergence using general principles (or there was a misprint)