# Prove "integral convergence" for a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, periodic-functions

Let $A$ be the compact annulus in the real plane with radii $2$ and $3$, and $(r,\phi)$ its polar coordinates. Define $F(r,\phi)=(r,r\phi)\ (\mod\ 2\pi)$. Is it true that, for a continuous function $g:A\to \mathbb R$, the integral $$\int_A g(F^n(x))dx$$ converges as $n\to+\infty$? ($F^n$ is the n-th iteration of $F$.)

My attempt was to prove that $F^n(x)$ is Cauchy for almost every $x$. This would allow us to apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, since $g$ must be bounded on the compact $A$.
But I just can't obtain the desired result, so I'm beginning to suspect that this can be false, and the convergence (if it is true) comes from weaker properties.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $F^n(x)$ is very much **not** Cauchy for almost every $x$. Instead, we have a sort of chaotic dynamics which thoroughly mixes up all points with given $r$ and various $\varphi$.

Comment: The function $F$ appears to not be well-defined if $r$ is not an integer, since $\phi$ is only defined mod $2\pi$ and so $r\phi$ will only be defined mod $2\pi r$.  Do you mean to always restrict your angles to be in $[0,2\pi)$ or something?  This will have a funny effect on what happens when you iterate $F$, since $F^n(r,\phi)$ won't just be $(r,r^n\phi)$...

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(mod\ 2\pi)$, of course.

Comment: An easier way to say this is $F(re^{it}) = re^{irt}.$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906754/prove-or-the-disprove-the-existence-of-a-limit-of-integrals/1907639#1907639